# CakePHP chmod question

Tags: php, cakephp, chmod

I downloaded CakePHP and put it in my www directory. I enabled mod-rewrite and all that and changed my document root. But I still get permission denied errors in my apache error log because Cake can't `require` the files from other directories. It's almost as if I need to chmod every single directory to `777` in order to make this work. I know that's not right but can someone tell me if I did not install it correctly or what to CHMOD. Because so far it's literally every folder I'm going through CHMODing right now.

Comment: you only have to chmod 777 for the tmp folder and its subfolders. What's exactly the error?

Comment: @Anh Pham: include(/var/www/app/config/core.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in blah blah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
chown -R <webserver_user> <cake_dir> #set the owner of your cake dir recursively to your webserver
chmod -R 755 <cake_dir> #set the permissions recursively
```

you can get the webserver user with

```
ps -aux | grep apache #or whatever your web server is
```